# Get normalized features from DimensionReduction?

Tags: dimension-reduction

When I feed a list of vectors with numerical values to `DimensionReduction` and use the resulting `DimensionReducerFunction`, the extracted features take on roughly normal distributed negative and positive values.

However, in machine learning applications it may be important to have the reduced feature space constrained to be positive and in the range from zero to one.

Of course I could try to map the new values onto that range; However, it may be the case that squeezing the data like that might distort relevant distances between values and so corrupt the data in the sense of numerical stability.

Is there a way to have the `DimensionReducerFunction` map to evenly distributed numbers on the interval zero to one?

Comment: This does not appear to be a well-posed problem.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Do you mean it is mathematically impossible to solve, or that I did a poor job expressing what I have in mind?

Comment: Somewhere in between those. You are aware of `Rescale` and also that it might introduce distortion. But then what criterion might a dimension reducer use that would both satisfy the desired coinstraints (values between 0 and 1) and not introduce distortion? I do not know if this is possible or even  makes sense. Iit is your task at least to indicate how it makes sense. That would entail giving a clear idea of how distortion-avoidance can happen. After which others might have a chance at figuring a suitable algorithm.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I see, yes, I thought there might be a trivial solution that I was just not aware of. Indeed, trying to map a gaussian curve to a straight line on the interval zero to one, there are two parameters in the gaussian but only one parameter in the straight line (its height). Seems overdetermined, unfortunately. On the other hand, both areas under the curves can be normalized, so in principle the reshuffling should be possible... I'll have to think more about it.

Comment: If the response by @AntonAntonov does not suffice, and if you do come up with a specification (or at least something close to a spec) for what you require, that would be of considerable interest. (I mean this to be encouragement because I suspect there is a goal lurking that might not defy analysis.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau See my answer posted below. What do you think?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable approach at least for the example at hand. I would guess there might be a large class of examples for which it applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define some sample data vectors to be dimensionally reduced

```
vecs = Table[
   a = RandomReal[]; b = RandomReal[];
   tb = Table[a Sin[a j] + b Sin[b j], {j, 1, 50}];
   tb - 2 Min[tb]
   , {i, 1, 10000}];
```

these look like they have some interesting features

```
vecs[[1]] // ListLinePlot
```

> [image]

Let's say, we'd like to reduce the dimension from `50` to `10`, so we take

```
rd = DimensionReduction[vecs, 10];
traf = rd /@ vecs;
```

Even though our initial data contained only positive values, the transformed vectors take negative and positive values from a roughly symmetrical distribution around zero

```
Histogram[traf // Flatten, 1000]
```

> [image]

To squeeze these vectors into an even distribution of values on the range from zero to one, we can assume that the number of examples provided was large enough to sufficiently map out the distribution, so that we simply label all values incrementally from zero to the largest number, and normalize by number of samples:

```
vals = traf // Flatten // Sort;
NN = Length[vals];
norm = (N[Ordering[Abs[vals - #], 1][[1]]/NN] & /@ #) & /@ traf;
```

With this, `norm` contains a representation of the dimensionally reduced data with values in the desired range and distribution:

```
Histogram[norm // Flatten, 1000]
```

> [image]

For the original seed data `traf` this map is exactly invertible, so that we can recover `traf` from `norm` by taking

```
trafRecovered = (vals[[Min[Max[Round[NN #], 1], NN]]] & /@ #) & /@ norm;
traf - trafRecovered // Abs // Max
```

> 0. 

Let us see how this inverse map behaves for a new set of test data outside of the initial seed set:

```
vecsTest = Table[
   a = RandomReal[]; b = RandomReal[];
   tb = Table[a Sin[a j] + b Sin[b j], {j, 1, 50}];
   tb - 2 Min[tb]
   , {i, 1, 1000}];
trafTest = rd /@ vecsTest;
normTest = (N[Ordering[Abs[vals - #], 1][[1]]/NN] & /@ #) & /@ trafTest;
trafTestRecovered = (vals[[Min[Max[Round[NN #], 1], NN]]] & /@ #) & /@ normTest;
```

We can investigate the deviation of `trafTestRecovered` from the original `trafTest`:

```
meanError = trafTest - trafTestRecovered // Flatten // Abs // Mean;
maxError = trafTest - trafTestRecovered // Abs // Max;
mean = trafTest // Flatten // Abs // Mean;
{meanError, maxError}/mean
```

> {0.000112784, 0.0254726}

We see that on average the mapping to evenly distributed values in the range between zero to one takes a toll of `0.01%`, while the maximum error that occurred was `2.5%`. Assuming that the dimensional reduction maps to a space that is stable under small perturbations, for all practical intents and purposes these errors are negligible and the data transformation is useful.

Answer (score 2):

> However, in machine learning applications it may be important to have the reduced feature space constrained to be positive and in the range from zero to one.

You can use the resource function [`NonNegativeMatrixFactorization`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NonNegativeMatrixFactorization): it reduces the dimension to matrices with non-negative values and it has a "Normalization" option.

Note that the "Normalization" option is for the norms of the "topic" vectors: the columns of the left factor and the rows of the right factor.

Here is an example:

```
SeedRandom[23];
{m, n} = {8, 5};
mat = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {m, n}];
mat = SparseArray[
   RandomSample[Most@ArrayRules@SparseArray[mat], Floor[2*m]]];

{W, H} = 
  ResourceFunction["NonNegativeMatrixFactorization"][mat, 2, 
   "Normalization" -> Left];

Norm /@ Transpose[W]

(* {1., 1.} *)

MatrixForm /@ {W, H}
```

[image]

---

> Is there a way to have the `DimensionReducerFunction` map to evenly distributed numbers on the interval zero to one?

It is not clear what you mean by this -- dimension reduction returns matrices with vectors that relate to each other according to the original data.

"Evenly distributed numbers on the interval zero to one" means that your original data has some very special properties.